# SQLite Database Graphics error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my MainActivity.java file. I'm trying to create a simple application to enter student name and then it'll store it in a database using the two other classes DatabaseManager.java and Students.java. The problem is that whenever I try to run the app and click on Add button, the app freezes and the error below shows up in the AppLogCat.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.dbms;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText inputText;
TextView outputText;
DatabaseManager manager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dataEntryText);
    outputText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    manager = new DatabaseManager(this,null,null,1);
    printDatabase();
}

public void onAddButtonClick(View view){
    String studentName = inputText.getText().toString();
    Students student = new Students(studentName);
    manager.addStudent(student);
    printDatabase();
}

public void onDeleteButtonClick(View view){
    String studentName = inputText.getText().toString();
    manager.deleteStudent(studentName);
    printDatabase();
}

public void printDatabase(){
    String dbString;
    dbString = manager.databaseToString();
    outputText.setText(dbString);
    inputText.setText("");
}


}
```

Students.java

```
package com.example.android.dbms;



public class Students {
private int _id;
private String _studentname;

public Students(){}

public Students(String _studentname) {
    this._studentname = _studentname;
}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String get_studentname() {
    return _studentname;
}

public void set_studentname(String _studentname) {
    this._studentname = _studentname;
}
}
```

DatabaseManager.java

```
package com.example.android.dbms;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;




public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "students.db";
private static final String TABLE_STUDENTS = "students";
private static final String COLUMN_ID ="_id";
private static final String COLUMN_STUDENTNAME = "_studentname";

public DatabaseManager(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_STUDENTS + " ("+
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
            COLUMN_STUDENTNAME + " TEXT );";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_STUDENTS +";");
    onCreate(db);
}

//add a new row to the database

public void addStudent(Students students){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_STUDENTNAME,students.get_studentname());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_STUDENTS,null,values);
    db.close();
}

//delete a row from the table

public void deleteStudent(String studentName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_STUDENTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_STUDENTNAME + "=\"" + studentName + "\" ;");
}

//print out the database as string

public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_STUDENTS + " WHERE 1;";

    //Cursor point to locate data in table
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while (!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_studentname"))!=null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_studentname"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
}
```

Error that shows up :

```
05-31 22:32:15.734 14795-14795/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-31 22:32:15.765 14795-14801/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
05-31 22:32:15.786 14795-14795/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown 
path: /data/app/com.example.android.dbms-1/lib/arm
05-31 22:32:15.922 14795-14795/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-31 22:32:16.051 14795-14810/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-31 22:32:16.114 14795-14810/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (Ifd751822f5)
                                           OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                           Build Date: 01/26/16 Tue
                                           Local Branch: AU12_SBA
                                           Remote Branch: 
                                           Local Patches: 
                                           Reconstruct Branch: 
05-31 22:32:16.116 14795-14810/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-31 22:32:28.290 14795-14805/com.example.android.dbms W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.405ms
05-31 22:32:28.312 14795-14805/com.example.android.dbms I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 96(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 90(8MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 8MB/14MB, paused 5.890ms total 32.806ms
05-31 22:32:32.319 14795-14805/com.example.android.dbms W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.073ms
05-31 22:32:34.343 14795-14805/com.example.android.dbms I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 84(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 81(10MB) LOS objects, 38% free, 8MB/14MB, paused 5.083ms total 18.483ms
05-31 22:32:36.545 14795-14801/com.example.android.dbms W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.236ms
05-31 22:32:37.036 14795-14801/com.example.android.dbms W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.119ms
05-31 22:32:41.672 14795-14805/com.example.android.dbms W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.867ms
```

Comment: this will help u https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html follow the example

Comment: didn't find anything which is helpful here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok Problem is in your **databaseToString** method replace it with following because it will not exit from loop

```
 public String databaseToString(){
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_STUDENTS;//+ " WHERE "+COLUMN_ID+"=1  if you want data for particular id

        //Cursor point to locate data in table
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);

       if( c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_studentname"))!=null){
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_studentname"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
        }while (c.moveToNext());
       }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
```

and i also recommend you to replace your **DatabaseManager** **constructor** to

```
 public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

so in activity oncreate replace

```
 manager = new DatabaseManager(this,null,null,1);
```

with

```
 manager = new DatabaseManager(this);
```

and you also have problem in **deleteStudent** replace it with below the problem was you are adding **""** to value instead **''**

```
public String databaseToString(){
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_STUDENTS;//+ " WHERE "+COLUMN_ID+"=1

        //Cursor point to locate data in table
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        do{
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_studentname"))!=null){
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_studentname"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
        }while (c.moveToNext());

        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
```

This https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html link provide u basic idea of insert,delete,update and select

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. There is one more thing that was needed to add and it was to check if the Table is empty set or not. App crashes if the Table returned an empty set. I put a constraint by using cursor.getCount()==0 and returning dbString with notification of empty database.

Comment: or u can add constraint with cursor.moveToFirst(); as edited in answer